# Getting InitializationProvider error after adding dynamic app module

Tags: android

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider androidx.startup.InitializationProvider: androidx.startup.StartupException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/lifecycle/DefaultLifecycleObserver;